# argocd-image-updater sets Application kustomize image, but deployment image stays the same

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, kustomize

**Describe the bug**

argocd-image-updater is running, sees valid candidate images from our docker.io repo, and updates them in the k8s Application, but the k8s deployment does not update it's image. Deployment image does have a kustomization.yaml. This is probably just a bone headed configuration issue in argocd-image-updater or in argocd, but I can't find any examples of a full argocd-image-update kustomization implementation. (I've posted this in their issues and did some digging, but the project has been pretty quiet). Even just some examples of a working kustomize example may do the trick here; **I'm mostly unsure how the Application image should update the kustomize image and thus the kubernetes deployment image**.

Updater logs:

```
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=info msg="Starting image update cycle, considering 1 annotated application(s) for update"
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=debug msg="Processing application doc-storage-ui"
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=debug msg="Considering this image for update" alias=doc-storage-ui application=doc-storage-ui image_name=cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui image_tag= registry=
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=debug msg="Using no version constraint when looking for a new tag" alias=doc-storage-ui application=doc-storage-ui image_name=cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui image_tag= registry=
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=debug msg="could not parse input tag latest as semver: Invalid Semantic Version"
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=debug msg="could not parse input tag pr-latest as semver: Invalid Semantic Version"
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=debug msg="could not parse input tag staging as semver: Invalid Semantic Version"
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=debug msg="found 5 from 5 tags eligible for consideration" image=cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=info msg="Setting new image to cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui:0.1.45" alias=doc-storage-ui application=doc-storage-ui image_name=cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui image_tag= registry=
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=info msg="Successfully updated image 'cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui' to 'cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui:0.1.45', but pending spec update (dry run=false)" alias=doc-storage-ui application=doc-storage-ui image_name=cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui image_tag= registry=
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=debug msg="Using commit message: "
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=info msg="Committing 1 parameter update(s) for application doc-storage-ui" application=doc-storage-ui
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=info msg="Successfully updated the live application spec" application=doc-storage-ui
time="2023-03-31T17:52:45Z" level=info msg="Processing results: applications=1 images_considered=1 images_skipped=0 images_updated=1 errors=0"
```

Application updated (notice that Images is the correct latest semver of cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui:0.1.45; sorry so verbose but may shed some light):

```
kc describe app -nargocd doc-storage-ui
Name:         doc-storage-ui
Namespace:    argocd
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/argocd.kustomize.image-name: index.docker.io/cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui
              argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/doc-storage-ui.update-strategy: semver
              argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: doc-storage-ui=index.docker.io/cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui
              argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/write-back-target: kustomization
API Version:  argoproj.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         Application
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-03-31T17:34:54Z
  Generation:          1422
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/argocd.kustomize.image-name:
          f:argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/doc-storage-ui.update-strategy:
          f:argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list:
          f:argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/write-back-target:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:destination:
          .:
          f:namespace:
          f:server:
        f:project:
        f:source:
          .:
          f:path:
          f:repoURL:
          f:targetRevision:
        f:syncPolicy:
          .:
          f:automated:
            .:
            f:prune:
            f:selfHeal:
          f:syncOptions:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:health:
        f:summary:
        f:sync:
          .:
          f:comparedTo:
            .:
            f:destination:
            f:source:
    Manager:      argocd-server
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2023-03-31T17:34:54Z
    API Version:  argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        f:source:
          f:kustomize:
            .:
            f:images:
    Manager:      argocd-image-updater
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2023-03-31T17:36:42Z
    API Version:  argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:health:
          f:status:
        f:history:
        f:operationState:
          .:
          f:finishedAt:
          f:message:
          f:operation:
            .:
            f:initiatedBy:
              .:
              f:automated:
            f:retry:
              .:
              f:limit:
            f:sync:
              .:
              f:prune:
              f:revision:
              f:syncOptions:
          f:phase:
          f:startedAt:
          f:syncResult:
            .:
            f:resources:
            f:revision:
            f:source:
              .:
              f:path:
              f:repoURL:
              f:targetRevision:
        f:reconciledAt:
        f:resources:
        f:sourceType:
        f:summary:
          f:images:
        f:sync:
          f:comparedTo:
            f:destination:
              f:namespace:
              f:server:
            f:source:
              f:kustomize:
                .:
                f:images:
              f:path:
              f:repoURL:
              f:targetRevision:
          f:revision:
          f:status:
    Manager:         argocd-application-controller
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2023-03-31T17:36:43Z
  Resource Version:  6907890
  UID:               830639e6-0df5-4135-9713-5ba57453a892
Spec:
  Destination:
    Namespace:  default
    Server:     https://kubernetes.default.svc
  Project:      default
  Source:
    Kustomize:
      Images:
        cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui:0.1.45
    Path:             argocd/prod/doc-storage-ui/k8s
    Repo URL:         https://github.com/upliv-health/iac
    Target Revision:  main
  Sync Policy:
    Automated:
      Prune:      true
      Self Heal:  true
    Sync Options:
      CreateNamespace=true
Status:
  Health:
    Status:  Healthy
  History:
    Deploy Started At:  2023-03-31T17:34:54Z
    Deployed At:        2023-03-31T17:34:54Z
    Id:                 0
    Revision:           e580c3e3b944f17c590a498bd27b7e35be088f86
    Source:
      Path:             argocd/prod/doc-storage-ui/k8s
      Repo URL:         https://github.com/upliv-health/iac
      Target Revision:  main
  Operation State:
    Finished At:  2023-03-31T17:34:54Z
    Message:      successfully synced (all tasks run)
    Operation:
      Initiated By:
        Automated:  true
      Retry:
        Limit:  5
      Sync:
        Prune:     true
        Revision:  e580c3e3b944f17c590a498bd27b7e35be088f86
        Sync Options:
          CreateNamespace=true
    Phase:       Succeeded
    Started At:  2023-03-31T17:34:54Z
    Sync Result:
      Resources:
        Group:
        Hook Phase:  Running
        Kind:        Service
        Message:     service/doc-storage-ui created
        Name:        doc-storage-ui
        Namespace:   default
        Status:      Synced
        Sync Phase:  Sync
        Version:     v1
        Group:
        Hook Phase:  Running
        Kind:        Service
        Message:     service/doc-storage-ui-service-cluster-ip created
        Name:        doc-storage-ui-service-cluster-ip
        Namespace:   default
        Status:      Synced
        Sync Phase:  Sync
        Version:     v1
        Group:
        Hook Phase:  Running
        Kind:        Service
        Message:     service/doc-storage-ui-service-loadbalancer created
        Name:        doc-storage-ui-service-loadbalancer
        Namespace:   default
        Status:      Synced
        Sync Phase:  Sync
        Version:     v1
        Group:       apps
        Hook Phase:  Running
        Kind:        Deployment
        Message:     deployment.apps/doc-storage-ui created
        Name:        doc-storage-ui
        Namespace:   default
        Status:      Synced
        Sync Phase:  Sync
        Version:     v1
      Revision:      e580c3e3b944f17c590a498bd27b7e35be088f86
      Source:
        Path:             argocd/prod/doc-storage-ui/k8s
        Repo URL:         https://github.com/upliv-health/iac
        Target Revision:  main
  Reconciled At:          2023-04-03T16:02:40Z
  Resources:
    Health:
      Status:   Healthy
    Kind:       Service
    Name:       doc-storage-ui
    Namespace:  default
    Status:     Synced
    Version:    v1
    Health:
      Status:   Healthy
    Kind:       Service
    Name:       doc-storage-ui-service-cluster-ip
    Namespace:  default
    Status:     Synced
    Version:    v1
    Health:
      Status:   Healthy
    Kind:       Service
    Name:       doc-storage-ui-service-loadbalancer
    Namespace:  default
    Status:     Synced
    Version:    v1
    Group:      apps
    Health:
      Status:   Healthy
    Kind:       Deployment
    Name:       doc-storage-ui
    Namespace:  default
    Status:     Synced
    Version:    v1
  Source Type:  Kustomize
  Summary:
    Images:
      index.docker.io/cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui
  Sync:
    Compared To:
      Destination:
        Namespace:  default
        Server:     https://kubernetes.default.svc
      Source:
        Kustomize:
          Images:
            cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui:0.1.45
        Path:             argocd/prod/doc-storage-ui/k8s
        Repo URL:         https://github.com/upliv-health/iac
        Target Revision:  main
    Revision:             e580c3e3b944f17c590a498bd27b7e35be088f86
    Status:               Synced
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age    From                Message
  ----    ------         ----   ----                -------
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  59m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  57m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  55m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  53m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  51m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  48m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  46m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  44m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  42m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  40m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  38m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  36m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  34m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  32m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  30m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  28m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  26m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  24m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  22m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  20m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  18m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  16m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  14m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  12m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  10m    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  8m53s  ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  6m52s  ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  4m52s  ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  2m52s  ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
  Normal  ImagesUpdated  51s    ArgocdImageUpdater  Successfully updated application 'doc-storage-ui'
```

Deployment not updated in k8s:

```
kc describe deployment doc-storage-ui
Name:                   doc-storage-ui
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Fri, 31 Mar 2023 10:34:54 -0700
Labels:                 app=doc-storage-ui
                        app.kubernetes.io/instance=doc-storage-ui
                        tier=web
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=doc-storage-ui,tier=web
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=doc-storage-ui
           tier=web
  Containers:
   doc-storage-ui:
    Image:      index.docker.io/cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui
    Port:       3000/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Command:
      node
      server.js
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   doc-storage-ui-68c575f855 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  35m   deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set doc-storage-ui-68c575f855 to 1
```

Deploymement yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: doc-storage-ui
  labels:
    app: doc-storage-ui
    tier: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: doc-storage-ui
      tier: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: doc-storage-ui
        tier: web
    spec:
      # Credential for private docker.com repository.
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
      - name: doc-storage-ui
        image: index.docker.io/cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
        command: ["node", "server.js"]
```

And the kustomize.yaml in the same directory as the deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- cluster-ip.yaml
- deployment.yaml
- loadbalancer.yaml
- service.yaml
images:
- name: doc-storage-ui
  newName: index.docker.io/cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui
  newTag: latest
```

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

- configure argocd similar to the above in yaml ^
- watch the argocd-image-update pod k8s logs and verify image found and updated
- Verify the Application image is updated as described above
- Verify the deployment image is not updated

**Expected behavior**
The image version to update in the deployment

**Additional context**
Newest installs for argocd and argocd-image-updater as of today.

**Version**
See above

**Logs**
Lots of logs above.

Comment: Have you tried to change the image name from `index.docker.io/cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui` to `cblairupliv/doc-storage-ui`? I guess this confuses kustomize

Answer (score 0):

It seems removing the registry prefix as (@TheDome mentioned) solves the issue in my case.
No idea why.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).